# The source file names are larger than is supported by the file system

Tags: windows, filesystems

Simple step for this issue. Cut folder from original location. And paste in other location or delete. Folder just few second task nothing else.

Note Microsoft Windows file system supported by only allows 258 characters. So that’s why we face this issue.

Comment: So shorten your filenames and path lengths?

Comment: *Windows* supports more then 32,000 characters in the path. Explorer, however, does not.

Comment: Please note that this post DESCRIBES certain symptoms but does not actually contain a question in it. In order to remain open and viable on this site the post must contain a specific and clear question.

Answer (score 2):

Possible solutions:

1. Shorten your original file names.
2. Move the files to paths with less "depth" and/or shorter total path names.
3. If you are using Windows 10, try [enabling long file name support](https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-10/enable-long-file-name-support-windows-10):

> 1. Start the registry editor (`regedit.exe`).
> 2. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem`.
> 3. Double click `LongPathsEnabled`.
> 4. Set to 1 and click `OK`.
> 5. Reboot.
>
> This can also be enabled via Group Policy via `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem > Enable NTFS long paths`.

---

*"In Windows 10 long file name support [...] allows file names up to 32,767 characters (although you lose a few characters for mandatory characters that are part of the name)."*

---

Comment: Just enabling this option has only an effect if the program uses the correct API methods (some API methods are still limited to 256 character paths) or in case of .net programs the application manifest contains the `ws2:longPathAware` set to true. More details can be found here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later

Answer (score 0):

I came across a suggestion online, but don't remember where I originally saw it. It's crazy simple and a bit hacky, but just works.

Use 7-zip (or WinRAR) to create a zip file and check the "Delete files after compression" option.

Be sure to create the zip file in another folder, such as c:\temp\

After compression, 7-zip/WinRAR will delete the files just fine, and you can go to the zip file you created and delete that too.  Done & Done!
[image]